# Symfony Form collections flush() error

Tags: php, symfony, formcollection

I have problem with form collection. I get an error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/.../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 103
```

i tried foreach (like is in doctrine documentation) and perist each object, but I get an error:

```
The class 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Entity, Ix\UserBundle\Entity, Ix\x\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model
```

Below is my code:

Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="availability")
 */

class Availability
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->availabilityFlexible = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->availabilitySession = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AvailabilityFlexible", mappedBy="availability", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $availabilityFlexible;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AvailabilityFull", mappedBy="availability", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $availabilityFull; 

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AvailabilitySession", mappedBy="availability", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $availabilitySession;

     // AvailabilityFlexible.php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Availability", inversedBy="availabilityFlexible", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="availability_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $availability;


    // AvailabilityFull.php
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Availability", inversedBy="availabilityFull", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="availability_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $availability;



    // AvailabilitySession.php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Availability", inversedBy="availabilitySession", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="availability_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $availability;
```

Form:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

    $builder->add('description')
            ->add('AvailabilitySession', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AvailabilitySessionFormType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ))
            ->add('AvailabilityFull', new AvailabilityFullFormType())
            ->add('AvailabilityFlexible', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AvailabilityFlexibleFormType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
    ));
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function addAvailabilityAction(Request $request)
 {
    $availability = new Availability;
    $availability->getAvailabilityFlexible()->add(new AvailabilityFlexible);
    $availability->getAvailabilityFlexible()->add(new AvailabilityFlexible);

    $form = $this->createForm(new AvailabilityFormType(), $availability); 

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $availability = $form->getData();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->perist($availability);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple times the same property in a class with PHP !!! You got 3 times $availability, don't you have exception with PHP xD ?

Answer (score 0):

Properties $availability are in different class.

1. AvailabilityFlexible.php
2. AvailabilityFull.php
3. AvailabilitySession.php

This is relationship to Availability Entity.